# How can I have these two <div>'s inside another <div>? When I make them <span>'s it doesn't work

Tags: css, inline, html

I was hoping you could enlighten me on how to have these two div's (or spans's if they need to be) fit inside of another div.  I need the sizes of the inner two divs to be a certain percentage of the larger container.  They also need to be next to one another.  I have tried a lot of different solutions on the web and stackoverflow and still seem to not be able to make it work.  Can anyone help?  The code snippet is below and I included a fiddle as well so you can better see.

```
body {
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
#content {
    border:solid;
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
}
.results {
    width:50%;
    height:70%;
    border: solid;
    /*overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;*/
    margin-left:7%;
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-bottom:8%;
}
.map {
    width:25%;
    height:70%;
    border: dotted;
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-bottom:8%;
    float:right;
}


<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="results"></div>
        <div class="map"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Here is the Fiddle for the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/9VXmw/)

Thanks for the help everyone!  I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: since `.results` is first in the document, if you add `float:left`, it should do what you've explained.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `display:inline-block` is what you are looking for.

Place it in `.results` and replace `float:right` in `.map` with it.

[Here is the updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9VXmw/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your help! That did solve the issue, but because the container that I am putting these two div's in is very large, at a certain size they go back to what I had described before.  When the container is larger (which is what I need), they again go underneath one another, but not when, say, the content div is only 500px.  Any suggestions as to what I can do further?

Comment: That's strange. It works fine on my screen even at a width of 5000px.
http://jsfiddle.net/9VXmw/4/ 
Do you have any other content around them?

Comment: I have a header on my own webpage that is above it.  I was playing around a bit and got it to work at content being 100% if I did float:left; on both of them and played with the margins.  Only solution that is currently working.  Thank you so much for your help though! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have both the inner div's fit inside the outer div, Just float them.
Since you haven't floated the first inner div that is why your second div is coming below that. `float:left` your `.results` div and it will do the job.

Here's the little modification to your fiddle : [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9VXmw/3/)

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: This also helps alot, thank you! Unfortantely, I was doing something that worked all along, but the content div is too large, so even when I float the inline div's....at a certain size they will again go below one another.  Do you have any advice for that?  For instance, if I made the content div 100% height and 100% width, this solution no longer works.  Any ideas?  it works in the fiddle but not on my own webpage.  Maybe some inherited property?

Comment: I tried setting width and height to 100% but it works for me. I can't see any problem. There must be something else that is messing with your code.

Comment: Try `box-sizing:border-box;`. That helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should `float:left;` on both `.results` and `.map`, and `clear:left;` on anything you want to put below that. Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/PHPglue/3Jfvp/ .